# Histogram visualization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I would like to plot several histograms in 3D using Matlab like in the below figure. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: "3D" Histogram Plot]

I use bar3 and histogram2, but both of them are not appropriate with the problem that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want with multiple calls to `histogram2`, one for each x value.

```
xs = 10:10:100;
ys = normrnd(50,20,numel(xs),5000);

colors = jet(numel(xs));
for i = 1:numel(xs)
    histogram2(repmat(xs(i),1,size(ys,2)),ys(i,:),'FaceColor',colors(i,:))
    hold on
end
hold off
```